# UIScrollView detect user taps

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimage

I'm using UIScrollView with PagingEnabled, inside UIScrollView I added three UIImage. It's work fine.

I'm wondering how can I detect if the user taps between two squares in UIImage,for example: in the attached image how can I detect if the user taps between squares 1 and 2 or if the user taps between squares 2 and 3?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sure I will add Gestures, but how can I detect touch location if it between square 5 and 6. @TotumusMaximus

Comment: You either create a view underneath 5 and 6 that has as frame, the minumum x of 5 and 6, the minimum y of 5 and 6, the width of max x of 5 and 6, the height of max y of 5 and 6. Then in the gesture handler detect which cube was closer (since u will have lots of these invisible views) or make some kind of view hierachy so that the once with more area are placed on a lower level of the screen.

Comment: If this is too advanced in your case you can just add a Gesture to the view that is behind these images.

Answer (score 1):

Add Gestures to image view

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
pgr.delegate = self;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:pgr];
[pgr release];
:
:
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
{
  //handle pinch...
}
```

Comment: also Check that userInteractionEnabled is YES on the UIImageView

Comment: I don't need the user moves the two fingers toward each other so I don't need to use UIPinchGestureRecognizer. @nivritgupta

Comment: Dont get why this answer gets a +1 since it is obviously not the answer he wants.

Comment: @Totumus Maximus   this  is one of the way , the user detect images over scroll view

Comment: he doesnt want to detect the images. He wants to detect the space inbetween the images.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting single or multiple taps use `UITapGestureRecognizer`, its a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer`. You should not forget to set the `userInteractionEnabled` property to `YES`, because `UIImageView`- class changes the default value to `NO`.

```
self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
// Set the number of taps, if needed
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
// and add the recognizer to our imageView
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // if you want to know, if user tapped between two objects
        // you need to get the coordinates of the tap
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.imageView];
        // use the point
        NSLog(@"Tap detected, point: x = %f y = %f", point.x, point.y );
       // then you can do something like
       // assuming first square's coordinates: x: 20.f y: 20.f width = 10.f height: 10.f
       // Construct the frames manually
       CGRect firstSquareRect = CGRectMake(20.f, 20.f, 10.f, 10.f);
       CGRect secondSquareRect = CGRectMake(60.f, 10.f, 10.f, 10.f);
       if(CGRectContainsPoint(firstSquareRect, point) == NO && 
          CGRectContainsPoint(secondSquareRect, point) == NO && 
          point.y < (firstSquareRect.origin.y + firstSquareRect.size.height) /* the tap-position is above the second square */ ) {
         // User tapped between the two objects
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok then after getting the coordinators do you think I will use if - else depending on the coordinators? @falsecrypt

Comment: I can't use that [firstSquare frame] because the square is within the image, it's not image it self.

Comment: locationInView wont work if u work with a property for imageview in this case. you can make a gesturerecognizer that fires a specific function too. Try making one for the view you places these images on. This to get a response when the user taps the view in between the images (just like ur question states)